# What is the relevance of studying the Markov Diophantine Equation And its Generalized Forms.

Tags: diophantine-equations

The relevance of the Markov equation and its Generalized forms are still a mystery to me. I cannot find anywhere online about the rational or relevance for studying the topic outside of pure curiosity.

The Markov Diophantine equation is

$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=3xyz
$$

One of its Generalized forms is the Markov-Rosenberger Diophantine equation
$$
Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2=Dxyz
$$

If anyone knows what the relevance of The Markov equations and its Generalizations or Where and/or how to find it. Please say.

Comment: That's a big problem with math research in general these days.  The resources are closed to us, in general.